# Rails, self-joined table, proper way of creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my web application I need to implement a supervisor/student relationship.  I need to join my "Person" table with itself through the "Supervision" table.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :supervised, :class_name => 'Supervision', :foreign_key => 'supervisor_id'
  has_many :supervisors, :class_name => 'Supervision', :foreign_key => 'supervised_id'

end

class Supervision < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :supervised, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :supervisor, :class_name => 'Person'
end
```

Now I need help regarding the controller.  I'm not sure if I need two controllers, one for supervised and one for supervisors, or just one "Supervision" controller.

Both the student and supervisor must be able to create a "Supervision".  I'm just not sure how to let the controller know whether the current user needs to be the supervisor or the student.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two controllers, but that would not be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so it is probably best avoided. You can either set up your routes so the URLs for Prof/Student appear to be different, but actually map to the same controller.

How many students a prof has:

```
the_prof = Person.find( *my record number* )
the_prof.supervised.count
```

Who they are is that same thing, so show their names

```
the_prof.supervised.each do |student|
  puts student.name
end
```

How to determine who is a professor or not? I would add a boolean flag to the people table: `is_prof`

My initial thought was the way to determine if a person was a student is they have no `supervised`. If a professor, they have no `supervisor`, but that breaks down if a Professor gets rid of all his students or the Student gets rid of all his Professors. Suddenly, we're in the land of *undefined*, which is **BAD**.

The flag also makes it easy to segregate all the professors and student, so you can do

```
profs = Person.find_by_is_prof( true )
studs = Person.find_by_is_prof( false )
```

(make sure to index that field in your database)

Comment: In terms of the application, I need to know how many students a professor has and who they are.  Both the professor and the student have access to the application, so it makes sense to give either of them a chance to add the relation.

Is this clear?

Comment: Answer fixed. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll end up making at least two controllers: one for people acting as supervisors, ie: one to manage one's subordinates; and one to manage one's own person record. You may even have another which manages a person's sign up and allows them to select their supervisor, as part of a kind of a wizard-style step.

Try mocking out how you want the application to behave first by sketching out some wireframes. Those will help you figure out which resources need to be changed from where.

If you find, for instance, that you need a list of one's subordinates, then that's probably a SubordinatesController#index page. Adding a subordinate would probably be a #new / #create pair in that controller.

Controllers are really about figuring out how the UI will respond to different user actions. Setting /my/ supervisor, and noting that I'm /someone else/'s supervisor are probably to very different things at the UI level. Just because they happen to reside in the same table doesn't mean that the UI has to reflect that symmetry.

It's strange that one would be able to change their own supervisor list. I think that's where the weirdness of your question arises.

Perhaps that's actually a side-effect of changing some other membership, like moving to a different group in the organization, in which case the reassignment would be part of its own controller.